# Retain symbology when merging layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, merge

I have a QGIS project with various layers for which I have assigned icons.  When I import additional data layers and then merge these layers with the existing layers (and their symbology) a new layer is created but without the symbology.

How do I merge an imported layer, without symbology, with an existing layer that does have symbology, and get a merged layer with the original symbology?

Comment: Either save the desired symbology as a `.qml`-file, or copy it to the new layer. Could this suit your needs?

Comment: To copy symbology from one layer to another, right click on the layer name > styles > copy/paste style.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?